# Android Room Database Optional paramater

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, room

I have an app on play store. I want to send a new update to play store but I have a doubt before sending the update. I made the parameters of my entitiy class in room to optional. Does this change require a database migration code? Thanks.

Comment: yes badiparmagi you need to add migration code

Comment: @Danialclarc, thanks. can you show me any resource about it?

Comment: you can have a look at https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929

Comment: @Danialclarc Sorry but I did not see anything about optional parameters?